# An "or" condition in Google Analytics Goal

Tags: google-analytics

When creating a Google Analytics "Goal", is it possible to put an `or` condition somewhere? Example:

```
Goal Purchase
=============

Destination = /thankyouforyourpurchase
OR
Event = [category Download, action Click, label Buy]
```

so this Goal can track different actions coming from different sources (site file download, payment success page displayed in browser, email, etc.)

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible using just the regular GA interface.

However, you might 'hack' this by firing off the event on the thank-you page as well and then using the event as the goal trigger?

Comment: Good idea @TheovanderZee!